# Hiding a SPA behind an authentication gateway?

Tags: javascript, authentication, reverse-proxy

I am building an application with the following planned login flow:

1. User logs in at 1.1.1.1:8080 at php web page.
2. php web page sends request to api at 2.2.2.2:8080 to create JWT access token
3. JWT access token gets sent to reverse proxy to authenticate with SPA at 3.3.3.3:8080.

It should not be possible to access the SPA frontend at 3.3.3.3:8080 without the JWT access token. If the auth is invalid they should be redirected to the php page at 1.1.1.1:8080. What free technologies exist to implement this? I was looking at nginx but it looks like it is only possible with nginx plus.

Comment: Do users directly access the SPA? Or do all users go through 1.1.1.1 or 2.2.2.2?

Comment: 1.1.1.1:8080 is the homepage where users login. After successful login with the api at 2.2.2.2:8080 users are redirected to the SPA at 3.3.3.3:8080.

Comment: What layers are hosting your SPA? Is it Nginx? AWS S3?

Comment: Ideally the SPA is being hosted behind a reverse proxy or web server

Comment: The login/landing page, SPA and API are separate units. The SPA and all of its components should be protected behind some kind of authentication architecture. I am looking for best tech stacks to implement this.

Comment: Gotcha, you could quite easily whip up a node server that verifies JWT tokens and allows valid requests through. Something simple like this npm package serves a folder(Your production build assets for your spa) - https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve. Then simply use a jwt verification npm package and you should be sorted.

Comment: Identity Server? https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Nginx does have a jwt module but its for nginx plus only.